# Rake: ArgumentError: unknown keywords: when passing method parameters

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I'm working on a pure Ruby application where I'm trying to create a Rake task. I have a method in the file `src/lambda_function.rb` that is as follows:

```
def self.process(event:, context: nil, box_api: BoxApi.new, form: nil, sns: SNS.new, kms: KMS.new)
            begin
                # verify request came from fromstack from headers
                verify_webhook_req(event)

                # parse data
                submission = JSON.parse(event["body"])
                form_id = submission.fetch("FormID").strip()
                submission_id = submission.fetch("UniqueID").strip()
```

As you can see from the above snippet the function takes in the following parameters:
`event:, context:, box_api:, form:, sns:, kms:` So in the rake task I pass the following:

```
require './src/lambda_function.rb'
require 'rake'
require 'pry'
include Rake::DSL


class KMS
    def initialize
    end

    def decrypt(key)
       return 'some password'
    end
end

class SNS
    def initialize
    end
end

namespace :test do
  namespace :lambda do
    desc 'Run the Lambda process function'
    task :process  do
      TEST_FORM_ID=3353951
      LambdaFunctions::LambdaHandler.process(box_api: BoxApi.new,
                                             form: TEST_FORM_ID,
                                             sns: SNS.new,
                                             kms: KMS.new)
    end
  end
end
```

But calling this rake task throws an error:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: unknown keywords: box_api, form
```

How come it doesn't recognize `form` and `box_api`. At first, I thought that maybe I was missing a hash to pass in the arguments. {box_api: BoxApi.new, form: ....}` this didn't work either.

Why is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I was calling a method in a different class which had different parameters.

```
class WebhookHandler
            def self.process(event:, context: nil, box_api: BoxApi.new, form: nil, sns: SNS.new, kms: KMS.new)
                begin
                    # verify request came from fromstack from headers
                    verify_webhook_req(event)
```